# Where to include play again code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is my rock, paper, scissors game but I would like to add play again function but not sure where and how. Thanks for help.

```
from random import randint

player = input('rock, paper or scissors?')
print(player, 'vs', end=' ')

chosen = randint(1,3)
#print(chosen)

if chosen == 1:
  computer = 'rock'

elif chosen == 2:
  computer = 'paper'

else:
  computer = 'scissors'

print(computer)

if player == computer:
  print('DRAW')

elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
  print('COMPUTER WINS')

elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors':
  print('YOU WIN')

elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors':
  print('COMPUTER WINS')

elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock':
  print('YOU WIN')

elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock':
  print('YOU WIN')

elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper':
  print('COMPUTER WINS')
```

Comment: Embed everything in a while loop

Comment: Put everything in a while loop and add a condition for play again :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything in a `while` loop

```
while True:
    layer = input('rock, paper or scissors?')
    print(player, 'vs', end=' ')

    chosen = randint(1,3)

    if chosen == 1:
        computer = 'rock'

    elif chosen == 2:
        computer = 'paper'

    else:
        computer = 'scissors'

    print(computer)

    if player == computer:
        print('DRAW')

    elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
        print('COMPUTER WINS')

    elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors':
        print('YOU WIN')

    elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors':
        print('COMPUTER WINS')

    elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock':
        print('YOU WIN')

    elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock':
        print('YOU WIN')

    elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper':
        print('COMPUTER WINS')
```

To make the code shorter I would recommend you to group the possible outcomes.

```
if player == computer:
    print('DRAW')
elif ((player == 'rock' and computer == 'paper') or
    (player == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors') or
    (player == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock')):
    print('COMPUTER WINS')
else:
    print('YOU WIN')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to check if the player still wants to play

```
from random import randint

playagain = 'y'
while (playagain == 'y'):
  player = input('rock, paper or scissors?')
  print(player, 'vs', end=' ')

  chosen = randint(1,3)
  #print(chosen)
  if chosen == 1:
    computer = 'rock'

  elif chosen == 2:
    computer = 'paper'

  else:
    computer = 'scissors'

  print(computer)

  if player == computer:
    print('DRAW')

  elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
    print('COMPUTER WINS')

  elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors':
    print('YOU WIN')

  elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors':
    print('COMPUTER WINS')

  elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock':
    print('YOU WIN')

  elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock':
    print('YOU WIN')

  elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper':
    print('COMPUTER WINS')

  playagain = input('Play again ? y/n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `while` loop and see if the player wants to play again:

```
from random import randint

while True:
    player = input('rock, paper or scissors?')
    print(player, 'vs', end=' ')

    chosen = randint(1,3)
    #print(chosen)

    if chosen == 1:
      computer = 'rock'

    elif chosen == 2:
      computer = 'paper'

    else:
      computer = 'scissors'

    print(computer)

    if player == computer:
      print('DRAW')

    elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
      print('COMPUTER WINS')

    elif player == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors':
      print('YOU WIN')

    elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors':
      print('COMPUTER WINS')

    elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock':
      print('YOU WIN')

    elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock':
      print('YOU WIN')

    elif player == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper':
      print('COMPUTER WINS')

    play_again = input('Do you want to play again[yes/no]? ')
    if play_again.lower() == 'no':
        break
```